# Why is a Context Free Grammar that is simultaneously in Chomsky Normal Form and Greibach Normal Form regular?

Tags: context-free, regular-expressions, normal-forms

In my course materials, there is one sentence about how if CFG is in Chomsky Normal Form, it is not regular, and if it is in Greibach Normal form, it also is not. But when a grammar is **simultaneously** both GNF and CNF, it somehow implies that the grammar is regular - why is it so?

I struggle to understand what would the productions of the grammar that is both in CNF and GNF look like. As in GNF, the production rule is in form: $A \rightarrow aA_1A_2...A_n$ such that the nonterminal sequence can be empty, I think that the only way a grammar can be in both normal forms, is when the production rules are in form: $A \rightarrow a$.

Even if this is the case, why does it imply that the grammar is regular? What is the relationship between regular and context-free grammar?

Comment: Hint: How many non-terminals can be "useful" in such a grammar and how many words can be generated from such a grammar?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "useful"? But is it all of the single letter strings of that alphabet? In which case that can be represented with a DFA?

Comment: by useful I meant those that can be derived from the starting nonterminal. Yes, all words that can be generated are one letter words.

Comment: Oh, but there are no productions of the form S -> AB, only A -> a, meaning that no strings can be produced from the starting terminal i.e. at all. The empty set is a regular language, therefore it is regular?

Comment: No the language is not necessarily empty, since $S \to a$ for each $a \in \Sigma$ is a valid production. But $\Sigma$ is finite. Thus...

Comment: Oh, I see. So, therefore as there is only one starting terminal, there can be only one "useful" production rule that yields in a single-letter string?